# Unable to plot the forecast in the original scale with autoplot

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecast, autoplot

I'm trying to plot the train set and the prediction in the same graph using autoplot but, instead of the value in the original scale, the output include the value in the transformed scale.
My train set has both the value in original scale and the value scaled. Is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```
#train the model
fit_prophet<-train%>%model(prophet(OrdAdj))

#forecast
fc_prophet <- fit_prophet %>% 
  forecast(h = "1 month")

#convert back in the original scale
fc_prophet$QtyEur <- InvBoxCox(fc_prophet$.mean, lambda)

class(fc_prophet$QtyEur)

fc_prophet%>%autoplot(train)
```

New code implemented after the suggestion:

```
fit_prophet<-train%>%model(prophet(box_cox(QtyEur, lambda=lambda)))

#forecast
fc_prophet <- fit_prophet %>% 
  forecast(h = "1 month")

fc_prophet%>%
  autoplot(train%>%filter(Date>="2023-01-01"))+
  geom_line(data=test,mapping=aes(y=QtyEur, x=Date), col="red")+
  labs(title="Train + Test vs Prediction")
```

[boxcox_inside_prophet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvw5q.jpg)

[boxcox_outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZwYA.jpg)

[new_autoplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2UBE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be confusing the way the forecast package works and the way the fable package works. With the fable package, you can include the transformation in the modelling step like this:

```r
fit_prophet <- train %>% model(prophet(log(y)))
```

Then the forecasts will be automatically back transformed to be on the correct scale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I've tried the suggestion but without success. 
I've put the new code in the question above and some images (the new autoplot, and even the components... when i try to transform the data inside prophet then it doesn't capture the additive term (figure 1) while if i transform the data outside the model and then fit them it captures the additive term (figure 2)

Comment: this problem is for the prophet and for the nnetar models (fable does not back-tranform the data). While the arima works well with the back transformation automatically done

Comment: The back transformation is handled for all models within the fabletools package. It is not possible that it works for some models and not others. I've tested it on fable.prophet, and it works fine.

Comment: yes, thank you! I solved the issue... i was implementing the code in the wrong way!